# java.lang.NullPointerException при попытке чтения из бд

Tags: java, mysql

При попытке считать данные из базы данных выдает ошибку java.lang.NullPointerException Как исправить?

```
 public List<Parametr> getParamsOfMaterial(int idOfMat) throws Exception{
    List<Parametr> list = new ArrayList<Parametr>();
    String query = "{call paramsOfMaterial(?)}";
    CallableStatement callStmt = null;
    ResultSet rst = null;
    try{
        callStmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
        callStmt.setInt(1, idOfMat);
        rst = callStmt.executeQuery();
        while(rst.next()){
            int id = rst.getInt("parameter_code");
            String name = rst.getString("parameter_name");
            String unit = rst.getString("unit");
            double value = rst.getDouble("parameter_value");
            Parametr tmpParametr = new Parametr(id,name,unit,value);
            list.add(tmpParametr);
        }
        return list;
    }

    finally{

        callStmt.close();
        rst.close();

    }             

}
```

Comment: Каким образом вы устанавливаете соединение?

Comment: Добавьте error stack